# Update Across Tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to set some values in my database and I can't get it to work. (I'm using SSMS 2008 R2)

The tables involved are `dbo.Scales` and `dbo.PosScore`.

`dbo.Scales` contains four columns:

1. `Grade (varchar)`
2. `Upper Bound (int)`
3. `Lower Bound (int)`
4. `Award (varchar)`

`dbo.PosScore` has two columns:

1. `Possible score (int)`
2. `Grade (varchar)`

I need to fill the `dbo.PosScore` table with the appropriate grade according to the bounds given in the `dbo.Scales` table.

It is best if it is referential i.e. if I change the boundaries then the table adjusts accordingly.

How should i go about this?

Comment: It sounds like you want a *view* that's created from a query joining `Scales` to a numbers table. Don't *store* data that you can *calculate* (unless the calculations are demonstrably causing performance issues)

Comment: What is the range of the bounds?

Comment: The ranges are about 10 each. The reason I need the table not a view is I want to then use that to plug into another table, that contains the scores that people actually got (amongst other things) and therefore these scores need to be linked to the grade and award columns in the first table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have two options if you want the values in `PosScore` to change when you alter the values in `Scales`: either create a trigger on `Scales` that (re-)creates the `PosScore` table whenever needed (or updates it), or use a view that changes dynamically. Unless the amount of data that needs to change is prohibitively large and recalculating the `PosScore` values takes too long a view should be the best option.

One way to create a view is to use a suitable table with a number range that covers the upper and lower bounds. Fortunately SQL Server has a system table that can be used for this very purpose (provided the range falls in the span 0-2047.

A query to create a view could look like below:

```
create view PosScore as
select s.Grade, number as "Possible score"
from master..spt_values v
join scales s on v.number <= s.UpperBound and v.number >= s.LowerBound
and v.type = 'P'
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ab69f/1)

Comment: The trouble with a view is that I can't use that result to feed into another table; I have described the situation in the comment on the question.

Comment: Not sure I understand; you can join against a view just like a table, but it sounds like what you want is to get the grade that corresponds with the actual score that someone got, and if so you should be able to join the actual score directly to the scales table. If you really need a table like PosScore then the best option is probably to have a trigger build it using the same logic as the view. For an example of a join with a view see this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3d4df/1

Comment: thanks, i didn't realise you could use a view in that way. many thanks